# React | Call a function outside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call the increment function of the `CounterText` from the `CounterButton`.

Note: This is not the particular case I'm trying to solve, but it's very similar. I have a stipulation: I can’t change the order of the items, they have to stay at one level, they have to be separate.

I have one root component looks like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div> 
       <CounterText/>
       <CounterButton/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CounterText looks like this:

```
const count = useRef(0);

function CounterText() {
  
  function Increment() {
     count.current++;
  }

  return(
     <h2>{count.current}</h2>
  );
}
```

CounterButton looks like this:

```
function CounterButton() {
    return (
       <button>Increment</button>
    );
}
```

PS.: Sorry for my English.

Comment: *"CounterText looks like this:"* I don't see how it can look like that. You can't call a hook outside of a component or hook, but that code has a `useRef` at what seems to be the top level of the code. (Also, that's not an appropriate use of `useRef`. You should be using `useState` within `CounterText`.)

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: (Irrespective of my comments above, thank you for doing a nice isolated example of what you're trying to do, even if I suspect the `CounterText` part of it may not be quite what you meant. Most people either do too much or too little. Nice one!)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you very much! (Yes, I messed up the CounterText part, it should be useState)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual solution is to [*lift state up*](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) into the parent component, and pass it down to child components as props or [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), along with a function they can use to update the state if needed, something like this:

```
function App() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const increment = useCallback(
        () => setCounter(c => c + 1),
        []
    );

    return (
        <div> 
            <CounterText counter={counter} />
            <CounterButton increment={increment} />
        </div>
    );
}

function CounterText({counter}) {
    return(
        <h2>{counter}</h2>
    );
}

function CounterButton({increment}) {
    return (
        <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    );
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;

function App() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const increment = useCallback(
        () => setCounter(c => c + 1),
        []
    );

    return (
        <div> 
            <CounterText counter={counter} />
            <CounterButton increment={increment} />
        </div>
    );
}

function CounterText({counter}) {
    return(
        <h2>{counter}</h2>
    );
}

function CounterButton({increment}) {
    return (
        <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) call there isn't *required*, but it makes the `increment` function stable, which prevents unnecessarily re-rendering `CounterButton` when `counter` changes.